# Simple map interface to create geo bounding boxes?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, geo

Hoping someone can point me to an existing resource so I don't have to create it myself.

Basically I need to get a series of lat/long coordinates that represent geo bounding boxes for Japan. The API the data is meant for allows multiple bounding boxes, so I want to create a series of smaller boxes that cover's about 99.9% of the country.

All I need to do is click on a map to indicate the north-east and south-west corners of a box, but I have been unable to find anything that quite does this.

The closest I found was this http://paulisageek.com/hacku/examples/geoBoundingBoxTabs.html. However it doesn't allow multiple bounding boxes, but more importantly doesn't provide the lat/longs that were calculated nor the ability to modify the boxes.

Comment: Just came across this: http://boundingbox.klokantech.com/, which doesn't allow multiple boxes, but allows editing them and getting coordinates.

Comment: chbrown's answer is good. Just used that to create 1 bounding box, and retrieve the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesnt look that hard with the new drawing tools library in the google maps api

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools

you get the coordinates, in callback event handlers.

Comment: Above link seems to be broken. I found similar functionality at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Comment: Yes, thats the same thing. The link just got broken with reorganization of the documentation.